# javascript run php function

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to make a simple casino website for a school project but I am having some difficulties with the javascript side of the game.

I found a Wheel of Fortune project online and wanted to use this:

```
var slicePrizes = ["100", "50", "500", "0", "200", "100", "150", "0"];
var prize;
var prizeText;

playGame.prototype = {
 winPrize(){
      // now we can spin the wheel again
      canSpin = true;
      // writing the prize you just won
      prizeText.text = slicePrizes[prize];

 }
}
```

Everything works! I only don't know how to get the var `slicePrizes[prize]` to a php function so I can implement my `php-->mysql` code? The file is saved as a .js file so I cant just open  I believe?

Comment: You'll need to use AJAX. Do you have to use vanilla javascript or can you use jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use AJAX to send the data to the server: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX